# How do i call this Ffun() and access this class?

Tags: java, function, class, object

How do i access the **F** class and call the *Ffun()*, btw am using jdk ver1.8.0_171

```
class A    
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B obj1=new B();
        B.C obj2=obj1.new C();
        B.C.D obj3=obj2.new D();
        B.C.D.E obj4=obj3.new E();

        obj4.Efun();

    }
}
class B
{
    public void Bfun()
    {
        System.out.println("In class B");
    }
    class C
    {
        public void Cfun()
        {
            System.out.println("In class C");
        }
        class D
        {
            public void Dfun()
            {
                System.out.println("In class D");
            }
                class E
                {
                    public void Efun()
                    {
                        System.out.println("Ind class E");    
                        class F
                        {
                            public void Ffun()
                            {
                                System.out.println("I need to get called");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Much thnx if u have found the way to call the Ffun(), i'm just writing this bcoz stackoverflow is not allowing me to post this question with so much of code and so little details.

Comment: You can't because `F` is a **local** class and goes out of scope one you leave the body of the method `Efun`. You can create an instance of `F` inside of that method though and use it there.

Comment: Deeply nested classes are definitely *NOT* a good idea.  Ideally, you just have *one* "public" class per source file.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, without changing the code.

There is no way to tell the outer world about a local class defined in a method.

You may write `new F().Ffun();` after you defined the `F` class, so `Efun()` would automatically call `Ffun()`.

```
class E {
    public void Efun() {
        System.out.println("In class E");

        class F {
            public void Ffun() {
                System.out.println("I need to get called");
            }
        } 

        new F().Ffun();
    }
}
```

The code is pointless, btw. No one would ever do that in the real world. Having a single inner class might be a subject of concern, not to mention your level of nestedness.

Comment: Thank you for noting "the code is pointless" and "No one would ever do that in the real world" ;)